# Ampscript HTTP GET with Authorization Header

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ampscript

I'm trying to connect to a 3rd party API using HTTP GET, however the endpoint requires **Header (Authorization: Bearer xxxxx)** to be sent as part of the request.

In PHP, it would look something like this:

```
$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Authorization: Bearer ".$token)
);
```

The [**HTTP GET Documentation**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/httpget.htm) doesn't have anything on sending headers, however the [**HTTP POST2**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/httppost2.htm) method does include a header value. The API endpoint only accepts GET requests, so I can't use POST in this instance.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer = Only possible with SSJS. 
Original Solution here: [HTTPGET Request in AMP Script with Bearer Token](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/232791/httpget-request-in-amp-script-with-bearer-token)

```
%%[
SET @token = "ExampleAPIToken"
]%%

<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

var mytoken = Variable.GetValue("@token");
var url = "https://example.com/api/auth";
var headerNames = ["Accept", "Authorization"];
var headerValues = ["application/json", "Bearer "+mytoken];
var response = HTTP.Get(url, headerNames, headerValues);
Variable.SetValue("response",response.Content);

</script>

Response: %%=v(@response)=%%
```

Reference: 
[SSJS HTTPGET](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_httpGet.htm)
[SSJS Set/Get Values with Ampscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_utilitiesVariable.htm)

Comment: Remember to mark your own answer as accepted, to indicate to community that there is a valid answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation doesnt mention header parameters for GET - but the HTTP GET AMPscript requests do support it if we pass the header name and value pairs as parameters in the function call.

I have shown the same in the video example as well - guess we need the SFMC documentation to be updated
https://youtu.be/uZaBn7GzrcU