# HTTPGET Request in AMP Script with Bearer Token

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ampscript, httprequest

I was able to successfully perform HTTPPOST using AMPscript with a header, but when I attempted to perform HTTPGET with a header, it is throwing a error. I referred the [**HTTPGet documentation**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/httpget.htm) which says header value cannot be passed.

Can this be done?

Comment: It'd be helpful if your question included the exact error message you're receiving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set headers in HTTPGet requests using AMPscript. You will need to use SSJS, or a combination of SSJS and AMPscript (if you want to set the retrieved content as an AMPscript variable).

The following code will make an HTTPGet request with a header and set the response as an AMPscript variable:

```js
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("Core","1");

var url = "https://httpbin.org/anything";
var headerNames = ["Accept"];
var headerValues = ["application/json"];
var response = HTTP.Get(url, headerNames, headerValues);
Variable.SetValue("response",response.Content);

</script>

Response: %%=v(@response)=%%
```

Comment: I have used the above code but the response is displayed as null, even I changed Variable.SetValue("response",response.Content) to Variable.SetValue("response",response.Status) expecting that it will be displayed as 500 or 400 but still displayed as null.

Comment: You should not change `Status` to `Content`. Leave it as `Content` to retrieve the content (otherwise it will be null). The above request works fine. If it's not working with your specific endpoint, I would recommend testing it in Postman and checking what response you get.